# Google Workspace API - gmail delegation access through php, permission denied

Tags: php, google-workspace

I have a piece of PHP code to try and obtain the delegate accounts of a given user.
lets say this user in my workspace is user@mydomain.com.

I have a service account (api@mydomain.com) with all permissions and from workspace > security > access and data control > api controls > domain wide delegation > the api client I have set a client with all the scopes that are listed in the php code as well.
Still, I recieve a permission denied as listed down below.

```
$scopes = array(
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic',
'https://mail.google.com/',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing'
);
$_mGClient = new Google_Client();
$_mGClient->setApplicationName("name");
$_mGClient->setAuthConfig($auth_config);
$_mGClient->setScopes($_mScopes);
$_mGClient->setSubject("api@mydomain.com");
$_mGMailService = new Google_Service_Gmail($_mGClient);

$delegateSettings = $_mGMailService->users_settings_delegates;
$delegates = $delegateSettings->listUsersSettingsDelegates('user@mydomain.com');
print_r($delegates);
```

Message:

```
Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Delegation denied for api@mydomain.com", "errors": [ { "message": "Delegation denied for api@mydomain.com", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } } in /GoogleAPI/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118
```

Now, I would not know where to set a setting to allow this to happen. I have enabled delegation for gmail as well in the workspace. Any suggestions to what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is likely due to the service account not being used to impersonate the target user, you can read more about it here:

- [The place where it says you need the domain wide authority](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings#:%7E:text=This%20requires%20use%20of%20a%20service%20account%20that%20has%20been%20delegated%20domain%2Dwide%20authority.)
- [The place where it is explained what domain wide authority is](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

The important part that is not explained that well there is that you also need to modify your code in order to determine which user is actually being impersonated, I was unable to find any examples of impersonation done specifically for this purpose but I believe you can use the information [here](https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/guides/how-tos/service-account#examples) to create your own version of impersonation.

I hope this all helps!

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is what you suggested but what I did is making the subject the account itself to which the delegate is added. So, in listUsersSettingsDelegates('user@mydomain.com'), user@mydomain.com is also used in $_mGClient->setSubject("user@mydomain.com"); which works. Is that your suggestion as well because it works for me. If not, maybe you can state a clear example in your comment because from the links you gave me this is what I figured out. These are helpful though!

Comment: To be honest I had a similar problem with Javascript but I don't really know PHP myself, I did however believe that you might find that info useful and I'm glad you did!

Comment: Then, does it mean that what I did was what you suggested or did I implement something else? to be sure :)

Comment: It is my suggestion however you made it work in php which I am not proficient at at all! :) koodos to you too!!!